# MongoDB - Removed Documents directly from Primary Shard

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem in production on my cluster.
Our monitoring fail on monitoring disk space and this over.
And i needed to remove some part of data directly on a master shard node.
I say on mongod with command:
`db.collection.remove({query})`

I know this is dangerous but is my only option at moment because i can't open mongo shell on mongos.
Now cluster works well but i need to know the real impact of my action.
And how to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The real impact is that you lose the data you deleted. There should be no other operational impact on the database itself. It should just return nothing when the affected documents are requested.

I'm sure you understand that this deletion directly into a shard (bypassing `mongos`) is not a recommended action by any means. In general, bypassing `mongos` could result in an undefined behavior of the cluster, and the resulting issue could stay dormant for a long time. In the worst case, this would lead to corrupt backup.

Having said that, deletion using the `mongo` shell (or a driver) is much preferred compared to going into the `dbPath` directory and deleting files. That action could lead into unrecoverable database.

The more immediate impact may be felt by the application, e.g. if your application expects a result and it receives none. I would encourage you to test all workflows of your application and confirm that everything is working as expected.